# How to set up Django admin search field?

Tags: django

I set up Django serach field ,

```
search_fields = ('publisher_number',)
```

publisher_number is IntegerField, 
let's say that I have publisher_number's :

1,5,10,13,18,20,25

When I type in django admin search field number  1 
I will get object with publisher_number: 1 , 10 , 13, 18

all which contain  number 1 ,

When I type 1 I want to get exactly object with  publisher_number : 1  not 10, 13,18 and similar

Attribut publisher_number isn't unique.

How I can override django search field method to search exacttly typed sting , not containing string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize this bevaviour by overriding (since 1.6)

```
ModelAdmin.get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results

There you do

```
.filter(publisher_number=search_term_as_int)
```

which gives you only publisher_number of 1 and not 10  or etc..

Comment: that is not what I want ,I don't want method to find  object , I want to override django admin search field  ,as I said I have search_fields = ('publisher_number',)  . when I type url

Comment: /admin/mydatabase/naruceniprodukti/?q=1      I will get all objects with  publisher_number which contain number 1 as  1 , 10 ,15 ,100  , I want to get  only object with  publisher number 1 , when I go to  /admin/mydatabase/naruceniprodukti/?q=1

Comment: @user3578448 this is only way you can achieve what you want in your question

Comment: Actually you help me a lot , thx,  below is how I did it...  def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        
        queryset, use_distinct = super(NaruceniProduktiAdmin, self).get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
        try:
            
            search_term_as_int = int(search_term)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            
            queryset = self.model.objects.filter(broj_narudbe=search_term_as_int)

        
        return queryset, use_distinct

Comment: I override get_search_results  but now list_filter don't works , I explained all in question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573742/list-filter-and-search-results-in-the-admin   ???

Answer (score 5):

```
search_fields = ('=publisher_number',)
```

by writing like this you can solve your problem.