# List filter and search results in the admin

Tags: django, django-admin

After I override the `get_search_results` method, `list_filter` is not working but the search field works as I expect.

```
class NaruceniProduktiAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('broj_narudbe', )
    list_filter = ('date', 'status', )
    list_display = (
        'naziv_produkta', 'datum', 'narudba_broj', 'boja', 'velicina', 'cijena', 'kolicina',
        'ukupna_cijena','korisnik_link','status','source_link',
    )
    actions = [dostupan, nedostupan, email_dostupan, placen, posalji_racun, poslan, isporucen, storniran, posalji_storno, ]

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, use_distinct = super(NaruceniProduktiAdmin, self).get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)

        try:
            search_term_as_int = int(search_term)
        except ValueError:
            search_term_as_int=search_term.strip()
            queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(korisnik__ime__icontains=search_term_as_int)

            if not queryset:
                queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(korisnik__prezime__icontains=search_term_as_int)
        else:
            queryset = self.model.objects.filter(broj_narudbe=search_term_as_int)

        return queryset, use_distinct
```

If I remove `get_search_results`, then `list_filter` works as expected. I want to keep it because I want the search fields to work how I expect, but I also want the list filtering to work as it normally does.

Is there a way that I can use both of these together? And is there a reason why one influences the other?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "`list_filter` is not working" ? what happens?

Comment: When I click on the right in Django admin to filter by date .. for example  today, ot last 7 days nothing happen

Comment: anyone ?   Main question is why get_search_results effect to work of  list_filter ..  Did Django use same method get_search_results  for search_fields and list_filter .. ?

Comment: yes, it looks like `get_search_results` is called in both cases, see `ChangeList.get_queryset` https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py#L356

Comment: it makes sense, you should be able to use search and filter simultaneously (i.e filter your search results)

Comment: Has anyone found a solution? Because I have get_search_results configured for search_fields affect list_filter. I still don’t understand how this should work, unexpected behavior!)

Answer (score 5):

Changelist view first makes filtering, then it gives filtered queryset as parameter to your `get_search_results` function. To make it work properly you should use `queryset` argument instead of `self.model.objects`.

```
def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
    queryset, use_distinct = super(NaruceniProduktiAdmin, self).get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)

    try:
        search_term_as_int = int(search_term)
    except ValueError:
        search_term_as_int=search_term.strip()
        new_queryset |= queryset.filter(korisnik__ime__icontains=search_term_as_int)

        if not new_queryset:
            new_queryset |= queryset.filter(korisnik__prezime__icontains=search_term_as_int)
    else:
        new_queryset = queryset.filter(broj_narudbe=search_term_as_int)

    return new_queryset, use_distinct
```